# How can I use "make" in windows? mingw32

Tags: c, makefile

I'm just a newbie. I don't know why "make" is not working. I did the instructions in the book.

-I created a makefile.txt

-I put the target, dependencies and the rule/command

```
encrypt.o: encrypt.c encrypt.h
gcc -c encrypt.c

practice.o: practice.c encrypt.h
gcc -c practice.c

executable: practice.o encrypt.o
    gcc practice.o encrypt.o -o executable
```

-I'm using 'tab' to indent those commands (gcc -c practice.c, etc. . .)
don't know why it's not indenting here.

-then in the command prompt I typed:

```
make executable
```

And this error came:

```
'-make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is there another process for Windows? I'm in Windows 10 using mingw32. I also have TDM-GCC-64. But since I'm a newbie, I don't have any Idea about them.

Comment: Apparently you either did not install the 'make' under mingw or it is not on your path. Does it exists somewhere, like /usr/bin or /bin or /usr/local/bin or in any other place? What is the value of your PATH variable?

Comment: I'm in the correct path. I really don't install it because I thought 'make' comes together with MingW32. . . So all I have to do is install it.?

Comment: on my windows box `make` is actually called `mingw32-make`

Comment: @yano.. thanks. I tried the same procedure and instead of typing make, I typed mingw32-make and the error msge has changed to:

      cc     try.c   -o try
      process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc try.c -o try, ...) failed.
      make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
     <builtin>: recipe for target 'try' failed
     mingw32-make: *** [try] Error 2

Comment: @yano I think that's it. But how are you using that mingw32-make?

Comment: My last mingw installation comes from strawberry perl and there is only dmake.exe; previously i found gmake.exe

Comment: This is an entirely different problem now. It's actually executing your makefile (which means `mingw32-make` is the name of your `make` executable) and running into problems trying to compile. Since this is a new problem and this question already has an accepted answer, you should create a new question, post your entire makefile, what you're trying to make, and the entire error message you are getting.

Comment: makefile.txt is not a valid makefile name.  Suggest `Makefile` or `makefile.mak`   Or if you really want to use a non standard name, Then invoke make via `make -f makefile.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbundle/files/latest/download -- with Mingw+msys

Only `msys`, you can download from: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjC5YyV1NXVAhUP1WMKHS6qDawQFghAMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fprdownloads.sf.net%2Fmingw%2FMSYS-1.0.10.exe%3Fdownload&usg=AFQjCNHKJSr677lkRS3MF0DiWTHCNldeXQ

`make` is inside `msys` package not `Mingw`.

[image]

Note: please update PATH environmental variable for `msys make` directory also.

Comment: It doesn't sense any logic to get the downvote without comments when I tried to help. This problem I got around 5 years ago when I used to use Windows.

Comment: Yeah. They're just down voting anytime they want. I'm just asking this because I'm really new to this. And this is not even a dumb question. I just don't have any idea about it for now.. Anyway, thanks for the link. I'll look for it later.